# tictactoe with php/ajax keeps failing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am a first year student so I am kind of new to this. For our course we have to make a tictactoe game with the use of Ajax and PHP for SQL-interaction. We used a client-side tictactoe, with javascript, as an example. However now we are stuck at the last piece of code. Basically what we did is make an SQL-query to retrieve the value of the boxes, and assigned all those to javascript variables, like this:

```
    var box0 = <?=$box1?>;
    var box1 = <?=$box2?>;
    var box2 = <?=$box3?>;
    var box3 = <?=$box4?>;
    var box4 = <?=$box5?>;
    var box5 = <?=$box6?>;
    var box6 = <?=$box7?>;
    var box7 = <?=$box8?>;
    var box8 = <?=$box9?>;
```

After that we wrote a long javascript code as the last option we could think of to make two arrays which keep track of the values (to determine who wins) and if a space is filled (to prevent changing an already filled in block). The javascript looks like this:
`

```
        //Global Variables

        var painted;

        var content;

        var winningCombinations;

        //Instanciate Arrays

        window.onload = function() {


            painted = new Array();

            content = new Array();

            winningCombinations = [
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
            ];

            if (box0 == " ") {
                painted[0] = "false";
                content[0] = "";
            } else {
                painted[0] = "true";
                content[0] = box0;
            }
            if (box1 == " ") {
                painted[1] = "false";
                content[1] = "";
            } else {
                painted[1] = "true";
                content[1] = box1;
            }
            if (box2 == " ") {
                painted[2] = "false";
                content[2] = "";
            } else {
                painted[2] = "true";
                content[2] = box2;
            }
            if (box3 == " ") {
                painted[3] = "false";
                content[3] = "";
            } else {
                painted[3] = "true";
                content[3] = box3;
            }
            if (box4 == " ") {
                painted[4] = "false";
                content[4] = "";
            } else {
                painted[4] = "true";
                content[4] = box4;
            }
            if (box5 == " ") {
                painted[5] = "false";
                content[5] = "";
            } else {
                painted[5] = "true";
                content[5] = box5;
            }
            if (box6 == " ") {
                painted[6] = "false";
                content[6] = "";
            } else {
                painted[6] = "true";
                content[6] = box6;
            }
            if (box7 == " ") {
                painted[7] = "false";
                content[7] = "";
            } else {
                painted[7] = "true";
                content[7] = box7;
            }
            if (box8 == " ") {
                painted[8] = "false";
                content[8] = "";
            } else {
                painted[8] = "true";
                content[8] = box8;
            }
        }`
```

So this should make two arrays containing the data we want to check. But when we try to run the following code, activated by an onclick-handler, simply nothing happens;

```
        //Game methods

        function boxClicked(boxid) {

            if (painted[boxid - 1] == "false") {

                if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                    content[boxid - 1] = "X";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "add.php",
                        data: {
                            id: boxid,
                            weapon: "X"
                        }
                    });



                } else {
                    content[boxid - 1] = "O";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "add.php",
                        data: {
                            id: boxid,
                            weapon: "O"
                        }
                    });



                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "count.php",
                });

                painted[boxid - 1] = "true";

                checkForWinners(content[boxid - 1]);

                squaresFilled++;

                if (squaresFilled == 11) {

                    alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");

                }
                location.reload(true);

            } else {

                alert("THAT SPACE IS ALREADY FILLED");

            }



        }




        function checkForWinners(symbol) {



            for (var a = 0; a < winningCombinations.length; a++) {

                if (content[winningCombinations[a][0]] == symbol && content[winningCombinations[a][1]] == symbol && content[winningCombinations[a][2]] == symbol) {

                    alert(symbol + " WON!");

                    if (symbol == "X") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "score.php",
                            data: {
                                player: "X"
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    if (symbol == "O") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/score.php",
                            data: {
                                player: "O"
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    playAgain();

                }

            }



        }

        function playAgain() {

            y = confirm("PLAY AGAIN?");

            if (y == true) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ".resetcount.php",
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    success: function() {
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                });

            } else {

                alert("Thanks for playing!");

            }



        }
```

So basically, can anyone tell us why we don't get any response at all by running boxClicked(boxid)? We expected it to run add.php with ajax and update the board with a new value filled in, and that the code would check on winners, end of game and if a box is already filled in. Thanks!

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommand you make use of the browser’s console, or else you’re going a way full of pain and tears. Push `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open your browser’s console.

From your script you can log messages by calling `console.log()`. It may be a good idea to log each one of your Ajax requests, either by passing a [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) handler to each `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "add.php",
  data: {
    id: boxid,
    weapon: "X"
  }
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log("add.php", data, textStatus, jqXHR);
});
```

… Or by registering a global [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) handler:

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions, data) {
  console.log(ajaxOptions.url, data, textStatus, jqXHR);
});
```

Now there’s the way you’re passing data from PHP to JS. It may be interesting to directly look at the generated JS file (by pasting its URL into your browser URL bar), you’ll probably see something like this:

```
var box0 =  ;
var box1 = X;
var box2 =  ;
var box3 = O;
var box4 = O;
var box5 =  ;
var box6 = X;
var box7 = X;
var box8 =  ;
```

Note the missing quotes. And that’s the problem when you attempt to generate source code: 9 times over 10 you have a problem with quotes. A less error-prone solution would be to pass data via Ajax in a common data exchange format, e.g JSON, XML or plain text.

For now, fix your PHP by adding the missing quotes:

```
var box0 = "<?=$box1?>";
var box1 = "<?=$box2?>";
var box2 = "<?=$box3?>";
var box3 = "<?=$box4?>";
var box4 = "<?=$box5?>";
var box5 = "<?=$box6?>";
var box6 = "<?=$box7?>";
var box7 = "<?=$box8?>";
var box8 = "<?=$box9?>";
```

Then you might also want to add a `console.log` in your click handler. Just sayin.

As for the rest of your code, I won’t spoil your dicoveries in the wonderful world of development, but let’s just say, there are definitely simpler ways to do it. Some hints:

- All these `if/else` tests could be refactored into a `for` loop.
- These 9 variables `box0` … `box8` could be in an array.
- You *might* not need these two arrays `painted` and `content`.
- You might also consider a 2-dimension array (3 arrays of 3 values each)…

Good luck ;)